# Error 'Too many connections' after upgrade the MySQL version in AWS instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I recently upgraded my MySQL version from 5.7 to 8.0.35 on my AWS instance. However, this database is utilized in my Laravel project, which currently runs on Laravel 6 with PHP 7.2.24. The size of the instance is db.t2.micro. Before the upgrade, everything was running smoothly. However, after the upgrade, I encountered an HTTP error code 500. In the logs, the error message displayed is:

> [Previous exception] [Object] (PDOException (code: 1040): SQLSTATE[HY000] [1040] Too many connections at /home/ec2-user/myproject/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:27)

i've been try to run this command :

```
sudo service supervisor restart
sudo service php-fpm restart
php artisan view:clear
php artisan queue:restart
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
```

but none of these are work.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide connection limit suggestions.